# Go Nested Json Marshall or Encoding

Tags: json, go, encoding, marshalling

For a project of mine, i need to encode into Json like below. I have all the values as variables. Any help is appreciated.

{"id":[{"name":"Test","Class":[{"Grade":"2","id":"34"}]}],"age":"5"}

this is the code i have tried

```
type classx  struct {
    Grade string `json:"grade"`
    Id string `json:"id"`        
}
type idx  struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Class []classx


}
type Response struct {
    Age  string     `json:"age"`
    Id []idx 
}
```

But getting an error  "cannot use classx literal (type classx) as type []classx in field value"

Comment: Show the line of code that generates the error "cannot use classx literal (type classx) as type []classx in field value".  The code in the question [compiles with no error](https://play.golang.org/p/JTz-lNheN9).

Comment: That's a compilation error. You have to show the code that you're using which generated the error (and the compiler will tell you exactly which line caused the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Class field is a slice. You have given it a struct

Wrong:

```
Response{Id:[]idx{idx{Class:classx{}}}}
```

Correct:

```
Response{Id:[]idx{idx{Class:[]classx{}}}}
```